# Beautifulsoup - Can't find element (href) in page source

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with **scraping** one element from the page - one href. The element is on the bottom of page, last section "Dowiedz się więcej o Pracodawcy:" and then we have this hyperlink "Zobacz profil pracodawcy". I try to find it by id, class, CSS selector - it doesn't work.

Interesting is that when I collect every href from my soup, it doesn't contain this specific url. Bellow my code and link to this page.

[Link page](https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/mlodszy-pracownik-utrzymania-ruchu-mechatronik-automatyk-walbrzych,oferta,1000823887?s=d8890351#company-details)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'b1cb9caz')))
btn.click()
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'bm6u2cu')))
btn.click()

html = driver.page_source
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
employer_url = bs.find('a', {'data-test': 'button-employer-profile'})

print(employer_url)
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, it gives me the href for "Zobacz profil pracodawcy". What do you see when you print `employer_url`?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is probably that loading the dynamic content after the second cllick is not yet finished before loading the data in selenium. Implementing a `time.sleep(5)` after the last `btn.click()` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about scrolling till the bottom of the page and *then* extracting the element?

Here's how:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/mlodszy-pracownik-utrzymania-ruchu-mechatronik-automatyk-walbrzych,oferta,1000823887?s=d8890351#company-details")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".employer-profilelnRpod").get_property("href"))
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://pracodawcy.pracuj.pl/company/20000293/profile
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. It looks clear to me, but when I have modified this code some error occurred. 
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".employer-profilelnRpod"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.114)`


Am I missing something?

Comment: It says there's no such element on the website. How did you modify the code?

Comment: I dealt with it. I had to add time.sleep after scroll script :) Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @Kacper_Te nie ma za co! =]